# I keep getting this error but don't know why "Invalid input. - input required but omitted"

Tags: programming, error, plc, ladder

Please help me by checking if my program is correct or giving the correct ladder program. I keep getting **"Invalid input. - input required but omitted"** this error for all the variables in first rung. I'm a newbie to ladder programming and done this much on what I understood by reading different sites on begginer ladder programs.

It would be also helpful if anyone could suggest me any source for
learning the ladder programming (ones with many programs with both the
problem statement & ladder program for each question).

***Automatic Bottle Filling System***

[image: Automatic Bottle filling System]
**Problem Logic**

***Step Conditions:***

1. Start and Stop PB is used to start and stop the process.
2. Start is pressed Conveyor starts moving until the Proximity Sensor is ON.
3. Then solenoid valve is open for 5 seconds. After 5s Conveyor should start moving.
4. Process should continue still stop push button pressed.

**Software used:**

SoftMaster Version 3.64 05/22/2012

Copyright @ 2005 Honeywell

Link to software user manual: https://www.honeywellprocess.com/library/support/Public/Documents/ug-soft-master-200.pdf

**Program Screenshots:**

***Screenshot of entire window along with ladder program***

[image: Screenshot of entire window along with ladder program]

***Screenshot of list of variables used***
[image: Screenshot of list of variables used]

***Screenshot of ladder program only***

[image: Screenshot of ladder program only]

Comment: Check your proximity_s symbol. Also once the proximity sensor opens there is no way to restart the system other then the start button.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. You seem to be trying to write to an input.*

If you have defined Proximity_Sensor as an input then you can't write to it. (I'm not familiar with the software so I don't know what address P00002 means.)

Try this:

[image]

*Figure 2. A possible solution. Image generated using [PLC fiddle](https://www.plcfiddle.com/).*

Comment: Tried changing it even tried removing last entire rung just before END but still the error persists @Transistor

Comment: Try the modified code. Add in a link (into your question - not hidden in the comments) to the user manual for the software.

Answer (score 0):

This specific error was because I didn't connect the OR'ed Conveyor_Motor switch directly to supply of ladder like in the image below:

[image]

This small change removed this error.

Comment: Good work. Now fix the code so that it works properly. See Figure 2 in my answer.